# 100% width table in email with single fixed width cell

Tags: html, html-email

I'm building a very simple HTML email. There is one table with one row and one cell. I want the table to be 100% wide (to set a background color that will fill the window) and the cell to be centered with a width of 600px. Trouble is it doesn't work. Is this possible? Thanks for any help I've spent an hour searching around the internet and haven't got very far.

```
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" bgcolor="#50917b"  align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" max-width="600" bgcolor="#999999" >
            content test
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't set attributes like `max-width="600"` and shouldn't set them like `bgcolor="#999999"`. Instead, use `style="max-width:600;background-color:#999;"`

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned I'm building a HTML email so want/need to be using HTML attributes rather than CSS inline styles. I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I have a feeling that it is not possible for the cells/cell to have a width less than the width of the table.

Comment: And you _have_ to use a table? I mean if you're just centering an element, why use a table at all?

Comment: Tables are the way to go for HTML emails. The single cell will contain my one column email. Vertical spacing, within the one column, is controlled by line spacing, breaks and line gaps. The table is to set my background color as this can't be set on the body tag.

Comment: You still can't use max-width as it is not a HTML attribute.  You can use width though.  If you want to use max-width inline you can use `style="max-width: 600px;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/paulalexandru/wwL4xL2y/show/) try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/wwL4xL2y/):

```
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" bgcolor="#50917b"  align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 600px; background: #999999;">               
                content test  
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as mentioned I'm build a HTML email, so DIVs are not supported.

Comment: Try now, this should definetly work. Inline styles work in html emails, it was because you had only one td, bud if you add other ones it will resize your td at 600px;

Comment: This works when content is added to the left and right cells (a non breaking space). Without the content, in Safari and Chrome, the cell has a width of non and the middle cell (containing my email newsletter) has a width of 100%. Thanks for your help

Comment: For clarity, it's not that `<divs>` are not supported, but more that floats are not supported. `<divs>` should therefore be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. outer table is 100% and inner nest table is 600px and aligned to the center. so this should work fine for you. : )

```
<body>
    <table class="wrapper" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
           <td bgcolor="#50917b" align="center">
            <table class="main" cellpadding="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">
                  content test
               </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```